# If $f(x)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ & $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a\neq b$ such that $f'(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ then $f$ has exactly one local min and max?

Tags: calculus

Prove or contradict:

> If $f(x)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and exist $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a\neq b$ such that $f'(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ then $f$ has exactly one local minimum and 1 local maximum

I know that $f'$ has only two roots which are $a$ and $b$ as the possible locations for min and max points, but how do I show these are necessarily or are not necessarily min and max points?

Comment: Check the sign of $f'(x)$ when $x<a$, $a<x<b$ and $x>b$.

Comment: Use second derivative test i.e. look at $f''(a)$ and $f''(b)$, whichever is $<0$ is the local maximum and whichever is $>0$ is local minimum. First, without loss of generality, assume $a<b$, then proceed with the test

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html

Comment: Alright cool! Got it thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} f''(x) = \left( x - b \right) + \left( x - a  \right) \end{align}
\begin{align} f''(a) = \left( a-b \right) \end{align}
\begin{align} f''(b) = \left( b -a \right) \end{align}
When \begin{align} a \gt b \end{align}
Then \begin{align} f''(a) \gt 0 \end{align}
And \begin{align} f''(b) \lt 0 \end{align}
When \begin{align} b \gt a \end{align}
Then \begin{align} f''(a) \lt 0 \end{align}
And \begin{align} f''(b) \gt 0 \end{align}
As you can see in both cases we have a local Maxima and minima

Comment: this only proves existence but not uniqueness

Comment: When \begin{align} a\gt b \end{align} then \begin{align} f''(a) \gt 0 \end{align} and \begin{align} f''(b) \lt 0 \end{align} so here \begin{align} a \end{align} is the local minima and \begin{align} b \end{align} is local Maxima also when \begin{align} b \gt a \end{align} then \begin{align} f''(b) \gt 0 \end{align} and \begin{align} f''(a) \lt 0 \end{align} so here \begin{align} a \end{align} is local Maxima and \begin{align} b \end{align} is local minima. So in both cases we have a unique Maxima and minima

Comment: First, you may want to know that in Mathjax, `$f'(a)$` produces $f'(a)$ and `$$f'(a)$$` produces $$f'(a)$$.

Comment: Now, let $g'(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x+1)$, then $g''(1)<0<g''(-1)$. However, $g$ also has a local minimum at $2$. And all your arguments apply to $g$ with $a=1$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: So what are you trying to say with this ???

Comment: Well, that OP asks to prove there is **exactly one** minimum and **one** maximum. However, your arguments all apply to the function $g$ I gave, and this function have two minimum. What you prove is only there exists a min and a max which is much weaker.

Comment: So let $ c $ be another local Maxima or Minima then so in that case $ f'(c) = 0 $ and $ (c-b)(c-a) = 0 $ solving this we get $ c=b $ or $ c=a $ which means only Maxima or Minima we can have is $ a $ or $ b $ and when $ a \gt b $ $ a $ is local minima and $ b $ is local Maxima and when $ b \gt a $ $ a $ is Maxima and $ b $ is minima(which I have proven in the answer). So in either case we have a unique Maxima and Minima

Comment: since $f'$ has only two roots (a,b) then those are the only possible maxima and minima points, and since there exists one of each there is exactly one of each. (basically what @Apruv said but less technically)

Comment: Exactly, but although this argument is relatively easy, it is essential to the solution of the problem and is clearly missing in the answer. This is what I wanted to point out!

Comment: @Jason To be completely precise, $f'$ has two roots and thus $f$ has two critical points. Apurv shows that there exists a min and a max, so these must the critical points and thus they the min and max are unique.

Comment: You're right but that part was obvious (at least for me) which is why I didn't notice it missing, but to be complete it should probably be in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Let $a<b$ without loss of generality. For $x<a$ we have $f'(x)>0$, for $x=a$ we have $f(a)=0$ and for $a<x<b$ we get $f'(x)<0$. This can be interpreted as $f$ is increasing up to $x=a$ and then decreases while $x$ approaches $b$ from the left. So $f(a)$ is a maximum. Similarly $f'(b)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x>b$ which implies that $f$ once it reaches $f(b)$ starts increasing. So $f(b)$ is a minimum. These two points $a,b$ are the only local extrema since $f'(x)$ vanishes exactly there by its very definition.

Comment: Currently, this is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The stationary point qualification is done with

$$
f''(x) = (x-a)+(x-b) = 2x-(a+b)
$$

hence we have

$$
f''(a) = a-b\\
f''(b) = -(a-b)
$$

so one of then is a relative minimum and the other a relative maximum deppending on $a > b$ or $b > a$